# Java object vs object array

Tags: java, oop, data-structures

Im a starter in Java. Recently I had a problem understanding the **copy(DbObject[] db)** method in this program, the source code is as follow:

`//Listing of a program to manage random access files.`

[Interface&Personalclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Quo.png)      [Dbclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z8zz.png)

Seems it copies the original record into the first element of db with type `**DbObject[]**`, but why not just copy value to db with type `**DbObject**`?

Comment: The value of every `Object` is a reference. And arrays are also `Object`s.

Comment: This is a very poorly worded question and the source code provided doesn't help us to answer your question. Where did you get the code from? Write a sample that shows how it's used, and where the confusion is cropping up. Then we can help you.

Comment: It looks like copy accepts an array of `DbObject` objects. What does `copy(DbObject[] db)` do? If I had to infer by the name and parameter it has, I'd imagine it takes an array of of `DbObject`s and for each one copies it.

Comment: Your updated code poses a couple questions. First who is calling `copy()`? And does the array contain any other `DbObjects`? Without any context on how and who is calling `copy()` its still a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an inference to what your asking, because I believe I know what your trying to get at, though without knowing what `copy(...)` does **exatcly** I can only make this inference.

Assuming `copy(DbObject[] db)` does as the name implies (which is probably copy `DbObject`s from the given parameter (i.e. the array `db`) to some other location then it makes sense for it to be an array.

Why? Well assuming the `copy()` does as I described, you would want to iterate through the array and for each of the `DbObject`s in the array, you would want to *do something*, whatever that something is. It wouldn't make sense to pass a single `DbObject` because you would have to call `copy()` several times for each object you would want to copy, as opposed to giving `copy()` an array of `DbObject` objects and having them all in one place.